# How do I share an OSX external drive with a Seagate GoFlex media box?

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive

At home, I replaced a Windows 7 box with an iMac running OSX Yosemite.
We used to stream our photos and (own homemade) music stored on the PC to
the TV set via a Seagate GoFlex media server. All I had to do was share drive I (the "My Book" external drive) on the PC and could log in on the media server to access its contents.

On OSX I've shared the "My Book" volume with everyone (Read access), but
the media server doesn't see it. In fact, it still has a button for the old Zak device (the Windows box) but doesn't pick up the new Loki device (the iMac). Do I need to add this device explicitly?

Nothing on adding more devices at http://www.seagate.com/docs/pdf/whitepaper/ug_goflex_tv.pdf

I'm also wondering about adding new devices, because from my laptop I
can see the other three shared/public folders on the iMac, but I can't see the "My Book" external drive share. So maybe I haven't shared the drive correctly?

Thanks again, S/U folks.

Comment: You have performed the intial synchronizing correct?  Almost sounds like you were using DLNA to share this media in the past.  Can you confirm?

Comment: All I've done is used the File Sharing tab in System Properties > Sharing to give everyone read access to the external volume.  I didn't do any synchronization, but I did install the Paragon NTFS driver so I could copy files to the external drive.

I didn't use DLNA. All I did was share the windows external drive, and connect an ethernet cable from the media streamer to the computer's hub, and it could see the machine.

I think I need someone who knows their way around the GoFlex product here. But thanks, Ramhound